# How to root LG Optimus L3 E400 smartphone?

Tags: rooting, lg-optimus-l3

I want to root LG Optimus L3 E400 Smartphone. I followed the instructions on this webpage: http://www.rootlord.com/2013/02/root-lg-optimus-l3-e400-smartphone.html but nothing happens. It says on the site that after the process is complete, there should be an app in the app drawer called "Superuser" with a green icon, but it's not there.

This is the model that Google Play displays: Vip MK LGE LG-E400

This is the output I get from the application:

```
[*]
[*] LG Spectrum Root Exploit (Windows version)
[*] by Dan Rosenberg (@djrbliss)
[*]
[*] Before continuing, ensure USB debugging is enabled, that you
[*] have the latest LG drivers installed, and that your tablet
[*] is connected via USB.
[*]
[*] Press enter to root your phone...
Press any key to continue . . .
[*]
[*] Waiting for device...
* daemon not running. starting it now *
* daemon started successfully *
[*] Device found.
link failed Permission denied
[*] Rebooting device...
[*] Waiting for device to reboot...
error: more than one device and emulator
error: device not found
[*] Rebooting device again...
error: device offline
[*] Waiting for device to reboot...
[*] Attempting persistence...
remount failed: Operation not permitted
failed to copy 'su' to '/system/bin/su`: Read-only file system
Unable to chmod /system/bin/su: No such file or directory
link failed Read-only file system
failed to copy 'busybox' to '/system/xbin/busybox': Read-only file system
Unable to chmod /system/xbin/busybox: No such file or directory
/system/xbin/busybox: not found
failed to copy 'Superuser.apk' to '/system/app/Superuser.apk': Read-only file system
[*] Cleaning up...
rm failed for /data.local.prop, No such file or directory
rm failed for /data/gpscfg/*, No such file or directory
Unable to chmod /data/: Operation not permitted
[*] Rebooting...
error: more than one device and emulator
[*] Exploit complete!
[*] Press any key to exit.
Press any key to continue . . .
```

<sup>[Original screenshot of the output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qZVSt.png)</sup>

Comment: Community bump prevention: this question was closed because the question seems to have been abandoned (the OP didn't have this device again and existing answers have not been voted on by anyone). If anyone can evaluate the existing answers, feel free to vote accordingly and reopen the question (or mod-flag the question requesting for reopening). For anyone else having the same issue, please post a new question and refer to this question as additional context.

Answer (score 0):

I tried using the same program and many others to root that phone and none of them worked, except for Key root Master MOD (this app is in Chinese but it still works as I have used it myself and successfully rooted my LG E400F).

**Instructions:**

1. Download the **Key root Master MOD**.
2. Sideload the APK
3. Click the second button **Mulai Root** and a popup will show
4. Click the button that says **root** and another popup will show a button in purple with 2 buttons (one red and one purple)
5. Click the **purple** button
6. Your phone should be rooted and have SuperSU installed
7. Optional: Use a [root checker](https://play.google.com/store/search?q=root+checker) to check if you actually have root privileges

This was the only root method that worked for me, as all the other ones didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

These apps might help you root it **without PC**:

1. [FramaRoot](https://forum.xda-developers.com/apps/framaroot/root-framaroot-one-click-apk-to-root-t2130276)
2. KingRoot

Usage is simple: just press the button and it will root your device. On FramaRoot, you don't necessarily need an internet connection. KingRoot requires an internet connection.

Comment: Thanks 4 the tip, but that phone is gone :D
But I'll be most great full if U could give some tips on how to root LGK4 2017.
Anyway, thanks again